# Issues when upgrading to Rails 4 with Sunspot/Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I recently upgraded my rails 3.2 app to 4.0 and upgraded Ruby to 2.0. I'm having issues now running Sunspot. It will start correctly but then when I navigate to a search page that sunspot is handling it throws the following errors. I've looked around but can't find anything.

Thanks for the help.

**Server Error**

> RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found Error: Not Found Request Data:
>   "fq=type%3AGear&start=0&rows=30&facet=true&f.category_name_sms.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=category_name_sms&facet.field=sub_category_name_sms&facet.field=state_s&facet.field=city_s&facet.field=price_s&f.sub_category_name_sms.facet.mincount=1&f.state_s.facet.mincount=1&f.city_s.facet.mincount=1&f.price_s.facet.mincount=1&q=%2A%3A%2A"
>   Backtrace:
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:268:in
>   `adapt_response'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in`
>   execute'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in
>   `send_and_receive'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in`
>   block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `block in instrument'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `instrument'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in`
>   send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' (eval):2:in `post'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:45:in`
>   execute'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:358:in
>   `solr_execute_search''

**SOLR Development Log Error**

```
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init()
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome
INFO: JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome
INFO: using system property solr.solr.home: /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer initialize
INFO: looking for solr.xml: /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/solr.xml
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer <init>
INFO: New CoreContainer 567038057
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer initialize
INFO: no solr.xml file found - using default
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer load
INFO: Loading CoreContainer using Solr Home: '/Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/'
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
INFO: new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/'
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting socketTimeout to: 0
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting urlScheme to: http://
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting connTimeout to: 0
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting corePoolSize to: 0
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting maxThreadIdleTime to: 5
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting sizeOfQueue to: -1
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory getParameter
INFO: Setting fairnessPolicy to: false
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil createClient
INFO: Creating new http client, config:maxConnectionsPerHost=20&maxConnections=10000&socketTimeout=0&connTimeout=0&retry=false
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer load
INFO: Registering Log Listener
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer create
INFO: Creating SolrCore 'collection1' using instanceDir: /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/collection1
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
INFO: new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/collection1/'
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig <init>
INFO: Using Lucene MatchVersion: LUCENE_41
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig <init>
INFO: Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
INFO: Reading Solr Schema
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
INFO: Schema name=sunspot
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
INFO: default search field in schema is text
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
INFO: query parser default operator is AND
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
INFO: unique key field: id
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore <init>
INFO: [collection1] Opening new SolrCore at /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/collection1/, dataDir=/Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/data/development/
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore <init>
INFO: JMX monitoring not detected for core: collection1
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore initDirectoryFactory
INFO: solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory get
INFO: return new directory for /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/data/development forceNew: false
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore getNewIndexDir
INFO: New index directory detected: old=null new=/Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/data/development/index/
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory get
INFO: return new directory for /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/solr/data/development/index forceNew: false
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /select: solr.SearchHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /query: solr.SearchHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /get: solr.RealTimeGetHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /update: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /update/json: solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /update/csv: solr.CSVRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: adding lazy requestHandler: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /update/extract: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: adding lazy requestHandler: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /analysis/field: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: adding lazy requestHandler: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /analysis/document: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /admin/ping: solr.PingRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /debug/dump: solr.DumpRequestHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /replication: solr.ReplicationHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /mlt: solr.MoreLikeThisHandler
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers initHandlersFromConfig
INFO: created /admin/: solr.admin.AdminHandlers
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader init
INFO: xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader init
INFO: xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader init
INFO: xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher <init>
INFO: Opening Searcher@1d70ec24 main
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker <init>
INFO: Hard AutoCommit: if uncommited for 15000ms; 
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker <init>
INFO: Soft AutoCommit: if uncommited for 5000ms; 
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent inform
INFO: Initializing spell checkers
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.spelling.DirectSolrSpellChecker init
INFO: init: {name=default,field=name,classname=solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker,distanceMeasure=internal,accuracy=0.5,maxEdits=2,minPrefix=1,maxInspections=5,minQueryLength=4,maxQueryFrequency=0.01}
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent inform
INFO: No queryConverter defined, using default converter
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler inform
INFO: Commits will be reserved for  10000
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
INFO: [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@1d70ec24 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1:1)}
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer registerCore
INFO: registering core: collection1
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
INFO: user.dir=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_solr/solr
Jul 30, 2013 11:48:47 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
```

**GEM's being used**

```
gem 'sunspot_solr', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
gem 'sunspot_rails', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
```

**Error Log when running reindex**

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Gear</query></delete>"

Backtrace: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:268:in `adapt_response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:131:in `delete_by_query'/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:268:in `adapt_response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:131:in `delete_by_query'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:57:in `remove_all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `block in remove_all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `remove_all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/retry_5xx_session_proxy.rb:17:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot.rb:464:in `remove_all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:183:in `solr_remove_all_from_index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:202:in `solr_reindex'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-5488725cb258/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: check if the solrconfig.xml exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up solving the problem, the following way.

1. First I uninstalled all versions of sunspot and SOLR.
2. Next I re-installed Sunspot with gem 'sunspot_rails'
   gem 'sunspot_solr'
3. I then added solr.rake to application/lib/tasks

> ```
> namespace :sunspot do
>   namespace :solr do
>   desc 'Start the Solr instance'
>     task :start => :environment do
>       case RUBY_PLATFORM
>         when /w(in)?32$/, /java$/
>           abort("This command is not supported on #{RUBY_PLATFORM}. " +
>           "Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.")
>      end
>
>   if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
>     Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.start
>   else
>     Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.start
>   end
>   puts "Successfully started Solr ..."
> end
>
> desc 'Run the Solr instance in the foreground'
> task :run => :environment do
>   if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
>     Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.run
>   else
>     Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.run
>   end
> end
>
> desc 'Stop the Solr instance'
> task :stop => :environment do
>   case RUBY_PLATFORM
>   when /w(in)?32$/, /java$/
>     abort("This command is not supported on #{RUBY_PLATFORM}. " +
>           "Use rake sunspot:solr:run to run Solr in the foreground.")
>   end
>
>   if defined?(Sunspot::Rails::Server)
>     Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.stop
>   else
>     Sunspot::Solr::Server.new.stop
>   end
>   puts "Successfully stopped Solr ..."
> end
>
> task :reindex => :"sunspot:reindex"
> end
> end
> ```

It worked after that. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: For step 2, how do you install with "gem 'sunspot_rails' gem 'sunspot_solr'"?   Can you give the exact command?

Comment: @AaronHenderson I think he means Bundle install from the gem file

Answer (score 0):

What parameters are you starting SunSpot Solr server with? I would guess you are trying to update to Solr4 (collection1 appears in Solr4) and the directory layout is wrong.

In Solr 3, the configuration files were in a **conf** directory right under solr home. In Solr4, you get one more level for collection, with default name **collection1**.

If I am right, you may need to create a subdirectory in your home with **collection1** and move **conf** and other directories under it.

Comment: I'm starting it with the command "bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start". From the Gem page https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Comment: I created a collection1 folder and moved the files from conf to the collection1 folder but it still through the error

Comment: Are you sure it is looking at the right path all together? Do you get path in the error message or do you set it somewhere? You may need to use some variation of truss/strace command to check where it is actually looking. Or try starting Solr explicitly with correct path as per the documentation on GitHub: 
**sunspot-solr start -- [-d /path/to/data/directory] [-b ip4_address] [-p port] [-s path/to/solr/home] [--pid-dir=path/to/pid/dir]**

Comment: I'm not sure how to identify if it's looking in the correct path. I've uploaded my Solr development log file. Hopefully that will help. I have confirmed I'm running Solr 4.2.0 and Sunspot 2.0.0